# How do I save GDI+ Graphics / HDC to a file?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I am unable to save a GDI+ Graphics object, which is derived from a Device Context HDC, to a file.

**What works**: I *am* able to save a GDI+ Graphics derived from a Bitmap. Sample code (Win32):

```
Color color(255, 0, 0);
Pen pen(color, 2.0f);

CLSID pngClsid;
if(GetEncoderClsid(L"image/bmp", &pngClsid) < 0)    // calls GetImageEncoders()
    return;

// Graphics from Bitmap - works OK
Bitmap bitmap(300, 300, PixelFormat24bppRGB);   // create Bitmap first
Graphics *graphics = new Graphics(&bitmap);     // create Graphics second
graphics->Clear(Color(255, 255, 255, 255));
Status stat = graphics->DrawEllipse(&pen, 50, 50, 100, 100);
assert(stat == Ok);
stat = bitmap.Save(L"C:\\temp\\test1.bmp", &pngClsid, NULL);
assert(stat == Ok);
delete graphics;
```

Result:

[image: *Graphics based on a Bitmap*]

**What fails**: If the Graphics object is derived from an HDC, I get a black rectangle. Regardless of whether I create the Bitmap at point [1], [2] or [3], I always get a black rectangle. Code:

```
CLSID pngClsid;
if(GetEncoderClsid(L"image/bmp", &pngClsid) < 0)    // calls GetImageEncoders()
    return;

// Graphics from HDC - fails
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
Graphics *graphicsDC = new Graphics(hdc);       // create Graphics first
graphicsDC->SetPageUnit(UnitPixel);
//Bitmap bitmapDC(300, 300, graphicsDC);    // [1] create Bitmap second. Black rectangle if called here
graphicsDC->Clear(Color(255, 255, 255, 255));
//Bitmap bitmapDC(300, 300, graphicsDC);    // [2] black rectangle if called here

HPEN penGDI = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, RGB(0, 255, 0));   // old school GDI
HPEN oldPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, penGDI);
Ellipse(hdc, 50, 50, 150, 150);
DeleteObject(SelectObject(hdc, oldPen));

Bitmap bitmapDC(300, 300, graphicsDC);  // [3] black rectangle if called here
Status stat = bitmapDC.Save(L"C:\\temp\\test2.bmp", &pngClsid, NULL);
assert(stat == Ok);

delete graphicsDC;
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
```

Result:

[image: *Graphics based on HDC*]

**Why I need this**: I am converting code that contains thousands of calls to the GDI API. I want to start using GDI+ gradually without converting all GDI calls to GDI+ at once. I have mixed GDI/GDI+ successfully in other cases, for instance when creating gradients. The only difference is that in the other cases, I wasn't trying to save to a file.

I can't use `CImage` because it doesn't have groovy anti-aliasing.

So, how can I save a Graphic as image when starting with an HDC?

Comment: I think you could `BitBlt` to the bitmap-based `Graphics` and save that.

Comment: `Bitmap` constructor that takes `graphicsDC` (point [3]) does not have to inherit or take over existing image, it only "...used to initialize certain properties (for example, dots per inch) of the new Bitmap object". I suppose you need to add code that copies image into this bitmap, then save it.

Comment: @alain  - Excellent suggestion. I can make it work by adding `graphics->GetHDC()` in the first example, thus giving me an HDC, and I can save successfully to a file. Thanks! Thank you also @Roman R.

Comment: You're welcome. I think the reason a window-dc can't be saved is because the pixels are in a (display-)device specific format, but I don't remember that exactly.